# Edge issue when getting XML element with Namespace

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to do this:

```
getElementsByTagName('m:properties')
```

It works in all browsers except Edge, where nothing matches. I am going down the path of assuming the namespace is the culprit. I've tried `getElementsByTagNameNS('m', 'properties')` with no luck. What else should I be trying?

Answer (score 0):

I've reached the conclusion that this is a browser issue that I need to handle separately. Edge *does* handle `getElementsByTagName('properties')` (without the namespace) so I fall back to that if the namespaced approach fails.